# Getting Audio and scores out of Jammit

Tags: audio, pdf

I've been using the Jammit app for learning songs and it's now not supported as the company that made it has gone bust. I've got a lot of tracks I've brought from them and they're still on my hard drive.....

I found a site https://github.com/mtolly/jammittools and it seems to have a solution which would do everything I need it to (extract the audio and score files for me to use outside of the app) but I have come up against a problem! I just don't understand how to use the software! As it's not for distribution to others but solely for my use, I'm just after getting the things back that I've paid for but can no longer access.....

I'm running an iMac 21.5 inch, Mid 2010, macOS Sierra v. 10.12.1

I've managed to get so that some of the command lines work, but I cannot locate the files within the Jammit app.......

Answer (score 1):

I've developed a fairly decent Macintosh tool to extract all the separate CD quality audio (WAV, AIFF, or MP3 formats), printable PDF files of all the scores and tabs, animated video synced to the music.

There is also  a player/mixer that lets you play along to the scrolling music, mute or adjust volume of individual tracks, slow to half speed, and loop sections.  It even supports Airplay so you can beam it your big screen tv and sound system.

We have a growing database of free downloadable content that members have shared.  If you have Jammit tracks and want to be able to use them in any Mac or Windows DAW, and hopefully share some of your files, you are invited to check out our page at https://www.facebook.com/groups/125340751305319/?ref=bookmarks

Or visit Crammit for Mac:  www.jammit.ca

Answer (score 0):

Here is a video on how to do it manually, I couldn't work out how to use jammittools either.  (You would need to find out the path for the songs, it is different to the executable path)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3Spxnnqdks

Answer (score 0):

If you only require playing the files, you can use an open-source replacement of Jammit:

http://unjammit.com